# my code is very slow compile when i set large number n. i do not know how to set loops

Tags: c++, c++11

c++ compile very slow
for 2d vector

```
std::vector< vector<double>  > V(n, vector<double> (n));
double sum2=0;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{

    double xai=xa1+i*dxa;
    double dxr=(double)(xr2-xr1)/n;
    double sum1=0;
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){

        double xri=xr1+dxr*j;
        V[i][j]=fun(xri,xai);
        double rect1=V[i][j]*dxr;
        sum1+=rect1;
    }
    double rect2=sum1*dxa;
    sum2+=rect2;    
}
return sum2;
```

Comment: How large is "large" for `n`? A [MCVE] needs to give us enough to reproduce your problem. Also, do you really mean it's slow to *compile*, or just slow to *run*? This code isn't `constexpr`, so *compile* time should be be unaffected by the value of `n` (it doesn't even know what `n` *is* at compile time).

Comment: this code is integrate 2dimension [ (1/2*pi)*exp(-xr^2/2)*exp(-xa^2/2)]. we can get the accurate answer if we set for example n=100000. that make the code is very slow.

Comment: With `n` of 100,000, `V` is 75GB large. Do you have this much RAM in your machine? Probably not, so the OS has to constantly swap to disk and back. Why do you feel the need to store function values at all? You use each value exactly once - you don't need this huge vector.

Comment: Your code assigns to `V[i][j]` on one line, reads it on the next, and never touches it again.  Remove the variable `V`, and do `double rect1=fun(xri, xai)*dxr;` directly.  It now calls `fun` 10 billion times, which will be your bottleneck; the program will take about a minute, plus 2-10 seconds for every cycle `fun` requires, give or take.

Comment: the integral for this equation equal to 1 at infinity limits so in c++ we have to increase limits and n to get the result equal to 1 as theory. in this case i have trouble in this code

Answer (score 4):

> - this code is integrate 2dimension [ (1/2*pi)*exp(-xr^2/2)*exp(-xa^2/2)].
> - the integral for this equation equal to 1 at infinity limits so in c++ we have to increase limits and n to get the result equal to 1 as theory.

If we apply Newton–Cotes quadrature to the infinite integral

[image]

, we need to cut off the lower and upper boundary of this integral.
The integrand must be negligibly small at the cut-off points.
Which value did you selected ?

The integrand of your problem is Gaussian and is rapidly decreasing like this,

```
 exp(-10*10/2) ~ 1.93 * 10^(-22)
```

which would be negligible in the present integration.
Thus, if we cut off lower and upper boundary by -10 and +10, respectively, and set enough points in this range, we should get precise result.

I actually got well precise result with 100x100 points using the following trapezoidal quadrature.
This quadrature is most simple one.
My test code is [**here**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nHBckKKdh6PQpiq8).

**1 dimensional integration:**

```
template<typename F>
double integrate_trapezoidal(F func, std::size_t n, double lowerBnd, double upperBnd)
{
    if(lowerBnd == upperBnd){
        return 0.0;
    }

    auto integral = 0.0;
    
    auto x = lowerBnd;
    const auto dx = (upperBnd - lowerBnd)/n;

    auto left = func(x);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i<n; ++i)    
    {
        x += dx;
        const auto right = func(x);
        integral += (left + right);
        left = right;
    }
    
    integral *= (0.5*dx);
    
    return integral;
}
```

**2 dimensional integration:**

```
template<typename F>
double integrate_trapezoidal_2dim(
    F func_2dim,
    std::size_t n,
    double x_lowerBnd, double x_upperBnd,
    double y_lowerBnd, double y_upperBnd)
{
    auto func = [&](double x)
    {
        return integrate_trapezoidal(
            std::bind(func_2dim, x, std::placeholders::_1), 
            n, y_lowerBnd, y_upperBnd); 
    };
    
    return integrate_trapezoidal(func, n, x_lowerBnd, x_upperBnd);
}
```

I am worried that you set finite but very large upper and lower boundary.
In that case, you need to set many points to increase the number of pints in the range of  -10 < x < +10.

Finally, there are various quadratures for numerical integrations.
If you insert something function into this Gaussian integrand, then Hermite quadrature or the fast Gaussian transformation (FGT) should be recommended.

Comment: Hi @john if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.